# ServiceStack: Accessing the session in InsertFilter and UpdateFilter

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a C#.net application in which I'm writing to a sql server database.  The SQL Server tables all have common record management columns (DateCreated, DateLastUpdated, CreatedUserId etc...) and I wish to abstract the population of these fields into an InsertFilter and UpdateFilter.

Here's a cut down version of the AppHost's Configure method..

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    ICacheClient CacheClient = new MemoryCacheClient();
    container.Register(CacheClient);

    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ConnectionString;

    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));

    container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
    var authRepo = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>();


    OrmLiteConfig.InsertFilter = (dbCmd, row) =>
    {
        var userSession = SessionFeature.GetOrCreateSession<AuthUserSession>(CacheClient);
        var recordManagementRow = row as IRecordManagement;
        if (recordManagementRow != null)
        {
            recordManagementRow.DateCreated = recordManagementRow.DateLastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (userSession != null)
                recordManagementRow.CreatedUserId = recordManagementRow.LastUpdatedUserId = userSession.Id.ToInt();
        }
    };
}
```

When executing I get the following exception on the first line of the OrmLiteConfig.InsertFilter delegate.  Does anyone have any better ideas for how I can retrieve the current user session id for insertion into the db?

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in ServiceStack.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: This AppHost does not support accessing the current Request via a Singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [User Session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) can only be accessed **within the context of a request** since it's dependent on the [Session Cookies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#cookie-session-ids) of the Current Request.

Only ASP.NET Hosts have access to the `HttpContext.Current` singleton to access the current request. You will get this exception when trying to access the Users Session in HTTP Listener Self Hosts without injecting the current HTTP `Request`, e.g:

```
var userSession = SessionFeature
    .GetOrCreateSession<AuthUserSession>(CacheClient, Request);
```

I recommend against trying to access to access the Users Session like this and instead create an extension method on `IRecordManagement` that populates the POCO similar to what your `InsertFilter` is doing, e.g:

```
db.Insert(new Record { ... }.WithAudit(Request));

//Extension Method Example:
public static class RecordManagementExtensions
{
    public static T WithAudit<T>(this T row, IRequest req) where T : IRecordManagement => 
        row.WithAudit(Request.GetSession().UserAuthId);

    public static T WithAudit<T>(this T row, string userId) where T : IRecordManagement
    {
        row.UserId = userId;
        row.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return row;
    }
}
```

Whilst I don't recommend relying on RequestContext singleton, you can use it in this case to set the current UserId for the Request in a Request Filter, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) => {
    RequestContext.Instance.Items["userId"] = req.GetSession().UserAuthId;
});
```

Which you would then be able to access from your filter, e.g:

```
OrmLiteConfig.InsertFilter = (dbCmd, row) => {
    ...
    recordMgt.CreatedUserId = RequestContext.Instance.Items["userId"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Demis,  I believe you've offered two workarounds - you recommend population via extension method on the POCO & also could in this example use a RequestFilter to populate the UserId onto the RequestContext.  I don't understand how I can go with the recommendation though, would you mind fleshing the syntax out a bit?

Comment: FYI: I've got the RequestContext workaround working but would prefer to go with the recommended approach as it feels cleaner to me.

Comment: @Drammy I've updated the Extension method to pass in the UserSession UserId since that's all you need. The extension method was meant to make the call-site code smaller (by retrieving the UserId in the ext method), so this change makes it more explicit at the cost of more code per call-site.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it - how do I add an extension method to an interface?  Thought you could only add extension methods to static classes??

Comment: @Drammy Extensions are defined in static classes but the `this` target can refer to anything, i.e. most of OrmLite API are extension methods over ADO.NET interfaces. I've updated my answer with an example.